# how to dynamically create a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have no problem creating the menu dynamically. 
My problem : the class submenu is not working. I assume it's because the alert doesn't appear.

When I hard code the li´s and do not create them dynamically, the submenu works.

I'm using .NET

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            mostrarGrupo01();

            $(".submenu").click(function () {
              alert("hola");
              $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
            })

        });

function mostrarGrupo01()
    {
       var k = 0;
       var grupo01;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Mesa.aspx/getGrupo01",
                    data: '{}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        grupo01 = response.d;
                        $('#grupos').empty();
                        $.each(grupo01, function (index, BEGrupo) {
                            //var r = $('<input type="button" value="' + BEAreaCC.DSAREACC + '" id="' + BEAreaCC.CDAREACC + '" name="' + BEAreaCC.CDAREACC + '" style="font-size:xx-large" onclick="botonClick(this.id, this.name, this.title);"/> ');
                            //var t = $('<li class="submenu"><button type="button" name="' + BEGrupo.CDGRUPO01 + '" onclick="mostrarGrupo02(this.name, this.id);">' + BEGrupo.DSGRUPO01 + ' </button> <ul></ul> </li>');
                            //var t = $('<li class="submenu"><button type="button" name="' + BEGrupo.CDGRUPO01 + '">' + BEGrupo.DSGRUPO01 + ' </button> <ul></ul> </li>');
                            var t = $('<li class="submenu"><a href="#">' + BEGrupo.DSGRUPO01 + '</a></li>');
                            $('#grupos').append(t);
                            k++;
                        });
                    },
                    failure: function (msg) {
                        $('#grupos').text(msg);
                    }
                });
            }
</script>
```

HTML :

```
<div class="contenedorMenu">
      <nav class="menu">
            <ul id="grupos">
            </ul>
      </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: but in the function mostrarGrupo01(), i create the li´s :                                     
                 var t = $('<li class="submenu"><a href="#">' + BEGrupo.DSGRUPO01 + '</a></li>');
                            $('#grupos').append(t);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML element with class `submenu` is added to your page dynamically.  You therefore need to bind your event in the following way:

```
$(".submenu").on('click',function () {
     alert("hola");
     $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the click event before `.submenu` is added to the DOM due to the asynchronous nature of `$.ajax`.

You have two options:

1 . Bind you click event within the `.ajax` success callback after you add the `.submenu` elements to the DOM

```
success: function (response) {
    ...
    $.each(grupo01, function (index, BEGrupo) {
        ...
    });

   $(".submenu").click(function () {
       alert("hola");
       $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
   })
},
```

2. Or change your click binding to target the parent `ul`

```
$("#grupos").on('click', '.submenu', function () {
    alert("hola");
    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
})
```